# How would an upcoming skit/act in the theater be announced in English?

Tags: phrase-request

An announcer in a comedy theater (I don't know how to call it; a small theater where actors are acting out some small funny skits) wants to prepare the audience for the next skit. So, he provides some background information for the upcoming act and wants the audience to clap their hands, thus, giving a signal for the actors to start performing.

What would the announcer typically say in this situation? Could he say something like "Please, welcome our next skit!", or "Please, welcome our next act!", or something totally different? (Not sure if it's okay in English to welcome an event instead of a person.)

I am especially interested in a case when the announcer wants to use a title for the skit. For example, "So, please greet our next act "The Tortoise and the Rabbit"!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in **stand-up comedy**, one introduces the comedian, not the act. That said, if more than one actor is going to be involved, act is OK.

**Please put your hands together for our next act, the Tortoise and the Rabbit.**

**Please show our next act, the Tortoise and the Rabbit, some love.**

or

show some love for our next act.

Those are two common ways you hear emcees introduce another act or comedian.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't even know that that "announcer" was called emcee in English.

Comment: By the way, you can leave out the please.....your choice. There is an HBO show called "I'm Dying Up Here", **all about this subject (comedians working in a comedy club)** and their travails. It might help you if you can find a way to see it.

Comment: emcee = M.C. = **M**aster of **C**eremonies

Answer (score 0):

"Please welcome our next act!" is fine - you are welcoming the actors, not the event.

If the announcer wants to use the title of the skit, use **with**:

"Please welcome our next act **with** *The Tortoise and the Hare*!"

or including the act's name:

"Please welcome our next act, Aesop, **with** *The Tortoise and the Hare*!"